# Quota: apply the same limit to all individual users of a group

Tags: linux, quota

I need to limit the disk usage of 10s of users. All the target users belong to the same group.

It looks `edquota -g <group-name>` enforces the limit across all users of the group. In other words, that command let ***all users of the group altogether*** allocate specified amount of disk. I want the restriction to be applied to each individual user independently. Is there any option in `edquata` for this goal?

The naive solution: Repeating the `edquoata -u <user-name>` for each user one-by-one.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your system support -p option of `edquota` then I think it is what you need.

Create prototype user, set up quota, then just run

```
edquota -p prototypeuser targetuser
```